# Confused on terminology - Module/Pallet vs Crate vs Package

Tags: pallet, substrate-recipes

My elementary understanding is that a Crate is a collection of modules or pallets, and a Package is a collection of Crates.
But I came across [this](https://crates.io/crates/pallet-balances) "pallet" in crates.io and am now unsure why it is self-referred to as a pallet instead of a crate.

Can someone please help me better understand with respect to this example?

Comment: Pallets are a special kind of crates, to be used in Substrate-based chains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do my best to explain it because in the beginning of my journey I was also confused with of all that terms.

`Crate` - the term comes from directly of Rust language and is the smallest amount of code that the Rust compiler considers at a time.

`Package` - the term also comes from directly of Rust language and is a bundle of one or more crates that provides concrete functionalities. A package contains a `Cargo.toml` file that describes how included crates should be build. `Package` is a feature of `Cargo` that lets you just build, test and share crates.

`Module` - the term also comes from directly of Rust language and is a place for [your code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html) where you can control scope of your implementation and logic of source code.

`Pallet` - the term comes from Substrate terminology and provides some set of functionalities within Substrate chain, below you can see set of pallets:

[image]

Additionally, you can be confused with meaning of `Frame` - `Frame` is like dialect of Rust language used in Substrate, but `Frame` is NOT Rust language term, `Frame` is the term used in `Substrate` framework.